# Embeded static helper class in Java type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to see if there was a better way to accomplish a scenario I have encountered.

I have a Message class that contains fields for a code, type, message body, and message source. The only field that is optional is source, so there are two constructors- one with all 4 args and one with only the 3 required arguments.

There is a use-case where I want to create a new message using one of any of the following pieces of information:

- Error Code (String)
- Error Code (Internal Enum Type)
- Specific Internal Type: A
- Specific Framework Error: B
- Specific Framework Error: C
- Generic Framework Error: D

And to do this I have employed an interface MessageHelper which contains prototype methods to accept the needed types (above). The Message type then has constructors that accept the various pieces of information that MessageHelper would then extrapolate the correct message fields from.

```
public Message(Message message) {
    this.messageType = message.messageType;
    this.messageCode = message.messageCode;
    this.messageBody = message.messageBody;
    this.source = message.source;
}

public Message(String messageCode) {
    this(messageHelper.newMessage(messageCode));
}
```

and to give some insight as to the inner workings of the message helper impl:

```
@Override
public Message newMessage(String messageCode, Object[] args, String source) {
    MessageType messageType = getMessageType(messageCode);
    String messageBody = messageSource.getMessage(messageCode, args, Locale.getDefault());
    // messageSource is of type ResourceBundleMessageSource
    return new Message(messageType, messageCode, messageBody, source);
}

@Override
public Message newMessage(String messageCode) {
    return newMessage(messageCode, null, null);
}
```

I have created the impl class for the interface and a bean to allow `@Autowired` as needed, but I am not sure the best way to access a MessageHelper instance from the Message type.

Currently there is a `private static MessageHelper messageHelper;` field int the Message class and I am calling `Message.setMessageHelper(...)` from a `@Configuration` file in my top level project.

However, I want to hide this configuration away and ideally have it done automatically by spring without explicitly calling the static set method. Is this a convoluted and or flawed thought process and implementation? Insight and or alternative implementations appreciated!

---

Edit: There is a bundle resource include that provides predefined message bodies and types with e code for reference

```
ERROR-CODE-1000=This is an error.
ERROR-CODE-1000.messageType=ERROR
```

Comment: would you know the message type/code/body at startup time? If yes then there is a more elegant way to achieve this otherwise it's not possible with Spring.

Comment: There is a bundle resource that is included in the jar at startup, I'll add an edit